# Java- Searching for trailing 0's in an array

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a 2D Array filled with consecutive integers 1-52 as well as four 0's.  I have also created a count variable and set it equal to 0;  I want to search through the array and for every 0 that immediately follows either 13,26,39, or 52, increment `count++`.

```
int count =0;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<4;j++) {
        if((board[i][j]== 13 && board[i][j+1]==0) || (board[i][j]== 26 && board[i][j+1]==0) || (board[i][j]== 39 && board[i][j+1]==0) || (board[i][j]== 52 && board[i][j+1]==0) ) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
while(count <4) {
    move(board);
}
```

My current code runs properly and will increment count for a single zero following these numbers. However I want to increment `count+=2` if one of my four numbers is immediately followed by two 0's (`increment +=3` for three 0's and `+=4` for four 0's).

Comment: What if ``a[i][n] == 0`` and ``a[i+1][0] == 13`` for example, does this count?

Comment: are you sure, you want to do this using arrays? and what about defining a method in that case that returns the count of successive 0's upfront one of those selected numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make another method to count zeros:

```
    int count =0;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<4;j++) {
                if((board[i][j]== 13 || board[i][j]== 26 || board[i][j]== 39 || board[i][j]== 52 ) && board[i][j+1]==0 ) {
                    count += numberOfZeros(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        while(count <4) {
            move(board);
        }
    }

    public int numberOfZeros(int i, int j){

        int aux = 0;
        for(; j<4;j++) {
            if(board[i][j] == 0){
                aux++;
            }
        }
        return aux;
    }
```

PS: I edited your if clause to make it more clear

Comment: you might want to put an `else {break;}` for non consecutive 0's.

Comment: Also the second loop should be ``for(int j=0; j<4 - 1;j++)``.  Or you might get a ``ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException``

Comment: @SchiduLuca If that would have been the case, even the code shared in the question wouldn't have marked *code runs properly*. Though I agree the question is not clear in terms of input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean to check whether you are on a count 'streak' of zeroes:

```
int count = 0;
boolean onACountStreak = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

        if (board[i][j] == 0) {
            // Count only if this zero is found in a streak
            if (onACountStreak) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        else if (board[i][j] % 13 == 0) {
            onACountStreak = true;
        }
        else {
            onACountStreak = false;
        }
    }
}

while (count < 4) {
    move(board);
}
```